# Laravel 10 SSR containers

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

Does anyone have an idea of how to establish a connection to an external container with Node.js and Vue Vite application in Laravel 10 using Inertia, which would facilitate server-side rendering?

Is it possible to configure (provider..) Laravel in a way that it will use a node process from a different container?

I have a separate Laravel and Node container. Everything works for me. But I can't embed according to this [documentation](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering) server side rendering. I followed the documentation and then tried to connect to another container. But can't find where to set it up.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into the same problem.